# Characterisation of graded homorphisms from a graded module to $\mathbb{R}[t]$

Tags: commutative-algebra, graded-rings, graded-modules

Let $\mathbb{R}[x, y]_d$ denote the vector space of homomogeneous polynomials in the indeterminates $x, y$ of degree $d$ with real coefficients. As a graded ring $A :=\mathbb{R}[x, y] = \bigoplus_{d = 0}^\infty \mathbb{R}[x, y]_d$ acts on the graded vector space $M := A(1)_{\ge 0} = \bigoplus_{k = 0}^\infty \mathbb{R}[x, y]_{k + 1}$ by multiplication: $f \otimes g \mapsto fg: \mathbb{R}[x, y]_d \otimes \mathbb{R}[x, y]_{k + 1} \to \mathbb{R}[x, y]_{d + k + 1}$.

Fix a graded ring homomorphism $\varphi : \mathbb{R}[x, y] \to \mathbb{R}[t]$.

Suppose that $\psi : M \to \mathbb{R}[t]$ is a graded linear map satisfying the property:
$$\psi(f g) = \varphi(f) \psi(g) \quad \quad \forall f\in \mathbb{R}[x, y], \forall g \in M.$$
For $k \ge 0$, given any $g = \sum_{i = 0}^k c_{i} x^i y^{k - i} \in \mathbb{R}[x, y]_{k + 1} = M_k$, is it true that $\psi(g) = \sum_{i = 0}^k c_i (ax)^i (by)^{k - i} t^k$ for some real numbers $a, b$ such that $\varphi(bx - ay) = 0$?

Comment: I don't follow the grammar at the end: $\psi(g)$ is a polynomial in the variable $t$; are $x$ and $y$ also real numbers? Or should those be $\varphi(x)$ and $\varphi(y)$?

Comment: Somewhat related, does $x\in M$ have degree 1 or 0? I'm not sure if there's significance to us writing $\bigoplus_{k=0} S_{k+1}$ instead of $\bigoplus_{k=1} S_{k}$.

Comment: As @EricNathanStucky says the equation "$\psi(g) = g(ax, by)$" doesn't make sense. Anyways I suggest you think about the case when no such $a, b$ exist, e.g. if $\varphi(x) := t^2$, $\varphi(y) := t^3$

Comment: $g$ is a polynomial in $x,y$, so $g =g(x,y)= \sum_{i,j} c_{ij} x^iy^j$ for real coefficients $c_{ij}$. Then $g(ax,by) = \sum_{i,j} c_{ij} (ax)^i (by)^j$.

Comment: $\varphi(x)$ cannot be $t^2$ since $\varphi$ is graded. Necessarily, $\varphi(x) = kx$ for some real number $k$.

Comment: $x\in M$ has grading $0$, namely $x\in M_0 = \mathbb{R}[x,y]_1$.

Comment: @ColinTan: Thanks for clarifying with the grading. Regarding your first comment: Sure, that's true, but $\psi(g)\in\Bbb{R}[t]$, so in what sense could this be equal to $g(ax,by)$?

Comment: OK, if you use the _standard_ grading (i.e. $\deg x = \deg y = \deg t = 1$) then $\varphi(x) = at$, $\varphi(y) = bt$ for some $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ (and again $\varphi(x) = kx$ doesn't make sense - note the use of $x$ versus $t$)

Comment: By the way, setting $S := \mathbb{R}[x,y]$, the more standard notation for your $M$ is $S(1)_{\ge 0}$, i.e. the truncation of the first twist of $S$ in degree 0

Comment: If $x \in M$ has degree $0$ as you say, and $\psi : M \to \mathbb{R}[t]$ is graded (of degree $0$), then please think about the consequences of sending $x \in M$ to a degree $0$ element in $\mathbb{R}[t]$

Comment: Eric Nathan Stucky and @math54321, thank you very much for your clarifying questions. I have fixed the formulation of the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately your revision still doesn't make sense: $\sum_{i = 0}^k c_i (ax)^i (by)^{k - i} t^k$ has both $x$ and $t$. You probably mean $\psi(g) = \sum_{i = 0}^k c_i a^i b^{k - i} t^k$, i.e. $\psi(g) = g(at, bt) = g(\varphi(x), \varphi(y))$, but even here there's still an indexing issue: since you insisted $x \in M$ has degree $0$, $\psi(x)$ has to be a degree 0 (not degree 1) element of $\mathbb{R}[t]$ (note that $\sum_{i = 0}^k c_{i} x^i y^{k - i}$ is in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]_k$, not $\mathbb{R}[x,y]_{k+1}$)

Comment: Anyways, here are the facts which solve your problem: set $\varphi(x) := at$, $\varphi(y) := bt$ ($a, b \in \mathbb{R}$). By $\mathbb{R}$-linearity, it suffices to define $\psi$ on the monomial basis $\{ x^i y^j \mid i + j \ge 1 \}$ of $M$. Now $\psi$ sends $x, y \in M$ to constants, say $\psi(x) = c$, $\psi(y) = d$ for some $c, d \in \mathbb{R}$, so it follows by computing $\psi(xy)$ in 2 different ways that $ad = bc$. Conversely, for any $c, d \in \mathbb{R}$ with $ad = bc$, there is a graded linear map $\psi : M \to \mathbb{R}[t]$ with $\psi(x) = c, \psi(y) = d$

Comment: thanks math54321